# Objective C: Custom keyboard extensions with images in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I have created custom keyboard in my application.Now i want to display only 8 images at the beginning and later after payment i want to display whole collection of images. I am checking condition for payment if its done then only show all images but i cant debug it why images are not displayed even though condition is satisfied.
Also my question is keyboard view is base class of UIInputViewController so it will hit only once after app execution.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Click on image resources and then File Inspector tab in right side. Check Targets are selected or not.